# C++ from C#: C++ function (in a DLL) returning false, but C# thinks it's true!

Tags: c#, c++, boolean, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm writing a little C# app that calls a few functions in a C++ API. I have the C++ code building into a DLL, and the C# code calls the API using DllImport. (I am using a .DEF file for the C++ DLL so I don't need extern "C".)

So far the API has one function, which currently does absolutely nothing:

```
bool Foo()
{
  return false;
}
```

In C#, I have the following:

```
public class FooAPI
{
    [DllImport("Foo.dll")]
    public static extern bool Foo();
}

...

bool b = FooAPI.Foo(); 
if (!b) 
{ 
    // Throw an exception 
}
```

My problem is that, for some reason, b is always evaluating to **TRUE**. I have a breakpoint on if (!b) and the debugger reports it as 'true', irrelevant of whatever the C++ function is returning.

Is the C# bool the same as the C++ bool? Though even if this wasn't the case, I still don't get how it would find the return value to be 'true' :)

Can anyone help me with this bizarre discrepancy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have the C++ function return true what does your C# method see as the return value?

Comment: Could you show us the code where you use the FooAPI.Foo() method?

Comment: Shouldn't your C++ function be declared extern "C" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `[return: MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.I1)]`. By default, C# interop [marshals C# `bool` as the Win32 `BOOL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx), which is the same as `int`, while C++ `bool` is one byte AFAIR. Thus, C#'s default marshaling expects the return value to be a `BOOL` in the `eax` register, and picks up some non-zero garbage because C++ `bool` is returned in `al`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes much more sense. Using a Boolean instead did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Your code snippet as posted cannot work.  If this was compiled with a C++ compiler then the function name would be `?Foo@@YA_NXZ` and your C# code could never find it.  The calling convention is important too, it is not the default (`CallingConvention.StdCall`) unless you tell the compiler.  And somewhere you should have told the linker to export the function.

Start by declaring the exported function so it is compatible with default P/Invoke attributes:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
bool __stdcall Foo() {
    return false;
}
```

Next problem is that the C++ compiler uses only one **byte** to store a `bool`.  The machine code generated for your return statement is:

```
013D138E  xor         al,al
```

The P/Invoke marshaller will however assume it is a 32-bit integer and check the value of the `eax` register.  Either declare the return type of the function as `int` or `BOOL` or use a `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]` attribute in the C# declaration.

Comment: Apologies, I am using a .DEF file instead of extern "C". I'll edit my original post. Had this not been the case, C# would have complained about a "missing EntryPoint".

Answer (score -1):

I used **signed int**.

C++ code

```
   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) signed int TestDouble(double* output)
    {   
        *output = 1.3;
        return true;
    }
```

C# code

```
 [DllImport("abc.dll", EntryPoint = "TestDouble", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern bool TestDouble(out double output);
```