# C# COM vaiable does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, c++, dynamic, com

I have a COM object in C#:

```
Class myClass = new Class;
IPClass myPointer = null;
myPointer = (IPClass) myClass.GetMyPointer();
bool myBool = myPointer.DoSomething();
```

myClass.GetMyPointer() in C# is returning a dynamic type. In the original code where the COM object is defined, myClass.GetMyPointer returns a pointer to an interface IPClass in C++.

When I test my C# dll, I could not get myBool. VS always says that myBool does not exist in the current context. But DoSomething was always performed. I just could not get the returning value back. I have tried to temporarily stop garbage collection from C# and it did not make any difference.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Please, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4621621/982431

Comment: myBool is not a "COM variable".  You get this kind of message from the debugger when you try to debug optimized code.  Which removes local variables.  Only debug code that was built in the Debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what it returns:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("calling DoSomething()");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((myPointer.DoSomething()).GetType().Name);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("finished call to DoSomething()");
```

Comment: The second line printed out the right type but myBool does not exist in current context....

Comment: OK, the problem was casting. The returning variable has to be exact the right type. If the returned type is a bool, I need to cast the myPointer.DoSomething() as (Boolean) myPointer.DoSomething(); If the returned type is a string, it needs to be cast into (String) myPointer.DoSomething()...