# C++ function to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

I am totally new to C++ programming. I need to call a C++ function from  C#.

C++ function is:

```
BOOL Usb_Init(HWND hwnd);
```

I've tried:

```
[DllImport("UsbComm.dll",  SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool Usb_Init( out IntPtr hwnd);
```

I got the Error message:

> PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature.

How to call the above C++ method?

Comment: It might be the [respective sizes of the bool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4621621/314291)

Comment: Possible c++ name mangling

Comment: @MickyDuncan If that was so then the error would be different. The error would report that the function could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following mistakes in the code in the question:

1. The C++ code uses `cdecl` and the C# code uses `stdcall`. That does not match.
2. The C++ code is passed an `HWND` by value. The C# code has an `IntPtr` passed as an `out` parameter. That does not match.
3. There are multiple spurious arguments to the `DllImport` attribute.

The correct C# declaration is:

```
[DllImport("UsbComm.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool Usb_Init(IntPtr hwnd);
```

You could set `ExactSpelling` to `true` but I see no compelling reason to do so. Feel free to add that if you prefer. There's no point in specifying `CharSet` since there is no text involved. And `SetLastError = true` is probably a mistake. It's unlikely in my judgement that the unmanaged function calls `SetLastError`. My expectation is that you added `SetLastError = true` whilst trying to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL` is defined as `int` in `<windef.h>`

You'll need to use `int` in the export declaration in C#. Reminder: a value of 0 equals `false`; anything else is `true`.

```
public static extern int Usb_Init(out IntPtr hwnd);
```

But also, your calling convention could also be wrong. Try each enum of `CallingConvention`

**EDIT**: The working signature is

```
[DllImport("UsbComm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Usb_Init(out IntPtr hwnd);
```

Comment: I tried     DllImport("UsbComm.dll")]
             public static extern int Usb_Init(out IntPtr hwnd); also called method    IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(0);
               var res = Usb_Init(out hwnd);   signature does not match error occured

Comment: [DllImport("UsbComm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Usb_Init(out IntPtr hwnd);

Comment: You've accepted this answer but it is not correct. The `hwnd` parameter is passed incorrectly. And there's no need to make the return type `int`. You can use `bool` in C# which is marshalled as the Windows `BOOL` type.

Comment: @David Heffernan: int value is also working fine.Which meets my needs.So i accept the answer.

Comment: `int` will work but it's needlessly complex. I'm surprised you ignore the mistake in the `hwnd` parameter. Hard to understand why you ask the question if you aren't prepared to listen to answers.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Sorry.I just looked out for a working solution.

Comment: I'm here to tell you that you will not find one in this answer. `out IntPtr` does not match `HWND`. Anyway, I've said my peace. I'm not going to try to force you to listen to me. I'll gladly help you if you wish to be helped.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you for your help.Can you please provide me C# signature for:BOOL Usb_IsConnectionValid(DWORD  dwUsbDeviceNumber);

Comment: `DWORD` is an unsigned 32 bit integer. That's `uint` in C#. The parameter would therefore be `uint dwUsbDeviceNumber`. Everything else is just the same as the function in this question.

Comment: @David Heffernan:It always returns false

Comment: I guess something is wrong then. Hard to know what exactly.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Can you please provide me C# signature for  BOOL Usb_GetDevicesList(int &iNbDevices, char aszDeviceName[][128]);

Comment: That's a new question. And quite a tricky one. You probably need to include more information. You cannot ask questions in comments. However, the question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293025/calling-c-method-in-c-sharp  I do think that you need to step back a little and read the help content for the SO site. You would get a lot more out of the site if you had a clearer understanding of how to ask good questions.

Comment: @ David Heffernan: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**C++ code:** Make sure definition of Usb_Init should look as shown below:

```
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall  Usb_Init(HWND hwnd)
    {
       return TRUE;
    }
```

**C# code:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Win32DllClient
{

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("UsbComm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool Usb_Init(out IntPtr hwnd);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
               IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(0);
               var ret = Usb_Init(out hwnd);
        }
    }
}
```