# WPF background thread crash

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, access-violation, direct3d

I’m working on a WPF app. Under rare conditions (when my app was able to load a file within 50 milliseconds – usually happens when loading a small file for the second time) some background unmanaged WPF thread crashes.

Can only reproduce in release builds, on both 32 and 64 bits platforms, with or without a debugger.

The exception says: *Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA7C088BB8 (wpfgfx_v0400.dll) in my.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.*

Or for 32 bits: *Exception thrown at 0x5CBB01F0 (wpfgfx_v0400.dll) in my.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.*

Stack trace 64 bits:

```
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CPtrMultisetBase::Remove(unsigned __int64)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CMilSlaveResource::UnRegisterNotifierInternal(class CMilSlaveResource *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CMilVisual::~CMilVisual(void)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CMilVisual::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CMILCOMBase::InternalRelease(void)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CMilSlaveHandleTable::DeleteHandle(unsigned int)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::ReleaseResource(class CMilSlaveHandleTable *,unsigned int,class CMilSlaveResource *,bool)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::Channel_DeleteResource(class CMilServerChannel *,class CMilSlaveHandleTable *,struct MILCMD_CHANNEL_DELETERESOURCE const *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::ProcessCommandBatch(class CMilCommandBatch *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::ProcessPartitionCommand(class CMilCommandBatch *,bool)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CCrossThreadComposition::ProcessBatches(bool)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CCrossThreadComposition::OnBeginComposition(void)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::ProcessComposition(bool *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::Compose(bool *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CPartitionThread::RenderPartition(class Partition *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CPartitionThread::Run(void)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CPartitionThread::ThreadMain(void *)
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

Stack trace 32 bits:

```
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CGlyphRunResource::DeleteRealizationInArray(class DynArrayIA<class CGlyphRunRealization *,2,0> *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CGlyphRunResource::Disable(void)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::ReleaseResource(class CMilSlaveHandleTable *,unsigned int,class CMilSlaveResource *,bool)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::Channel_DeleteResource(class CMilServerChannel *,class CMilSlaveHandleTable *,struct MILCMD_CHANNEL_DELETERESOURCE const *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::ProcessCommandBatch(class CMilCommandBatch *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::ProcessPartitionCommand(class CMilCommandBatch *,bool)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CCrossThreadComposition::ProcessBatches(bool)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CCrossThreadComposition::OnBeginComposition(void)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::ProcessComposition(bool *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CComposition::Compose(bool *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CPartitionThread::RenderPartition(class Partition *)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CPartitionThread::Run(void)
wpfgfx_v0400.dll!CPartitionThread::ThreadMain(void *)
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

At the same time, my own threads do nothing interesting. For example, main tread is usually sleeping in WindowsBase.dll!Dispatcher.GetMessage

For now I added a delay, so if the file was loaded too fast, I just wait till 100 milliseconds is elapsed.

However, I’d like to implement proper fix, without waiting.

Is there a way to find out what exactly those WPF background thread is trying to do, and why it crashes?

Comment: Any code using background threads on startup? Or possibly you're using a library that uses background threads? If so show us please.

Comment: What sort of file?  Is it a resource file your program uses?

Comment: The app is complex, and yes, there are other threads running, both managed (mostly CLR thread pool) and native (sometimes OpenMP, sometimes Vista+ thread pool).
However, only three threads are somehow related with the GUI.
Main thread (obviously), second GUI thread (runs separate WPF window on another display), and my background D3D11 renderer. At the time of the crash, they all wait for something (both GUI threads for windows messages deep inside WPF framework, render thread for my Monitor object).
Not sure what exactly can I show.

Comment: @B.K. Data file. In my application, I repeatedly press File/Open or File/Recent, and the crash happens. Also it doesn’t matter, I can reproduce the crash even if I replace loading with e.g. await Task.Delay(5). Looks like it’s some loading GUI that crashing WPF: while a file’s loading I disable main window menu, overlay dark background, show a “please wait” popup with a progress bar…

Comment: Well, it's really hard to tell without code.  I don't know if this will even remotely help you, but I found this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846209/0xc0000005-access-violation-reading-location-0xffffffffffffffff

Comment: Yeah.. Problem is, that whole crashing thread is WPF implementation details. No one besides Microsoft has the code. I only have debug symbols from MS symbol server, that's how I have a call stacks.

Comment: BTW, if I remove the second GUI thread (i.e. run second window on the main thread) nothing changes. So, second GUI thread isn't relevant.

Comment: Looks like some shared COM object is being released, and that causes race conditions. I'd suggest keep reducing, until you get the smallest repro - that might give you more hints. Try disabling D3D activities, and see if that reproes. If it doesn't - see if you can change the initialization order. That easily could be a graphics adapter driver issue (try another machine)

Comment: @Soonts Could you file a Connect bug via http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio 
Would appreciate if you could also send a iDNA trace to help us better diagnose this issue.