# C# calling C++ DLL returns incorrect value

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, dll

I have no further ideas how to debug this bug, so asking for advice.

Essentially, I have a C++ DLL, which has a boolean function

```
class Point
{
   Public: 
   double x;
   double y;

   // lots of operators
}

typedef struct SomeStructParent
{
    bool isValid;

    int64_t StartTime;
    int64_t EndTime;
} SomeStructParent;

typedef struct SomeStruct : SomeStructParent
{
    Point Center;
} SomeStruct;

bool func(SomeStruct & arg)
   { return some_var; }
```

`some_var` is initiated to false. The only place in the code where it is set to true has a logger printing. The return value of func is also printed to logger regularly.

C# imports the function like so:

```
public struct EtPoint
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SomeStruct 
    {
        bool isValid;

        // in milliseconds using tracker epoch
        public long StartTime;
        long EndTime;

        public EtPoint Center;       
    }

[DllImport("ETHAL.dll", EntryPoint = "func", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool func(ref SomeStruct data);
```

Under some conditions, calling `func` from C# returns true, even though the logger shows it as false - the regular prints are false and the line that shows it was set does not occur. With a modified function bool `funcArg(SomeStruct & arg, bool & ret) { ret = some_var; }`, `ret` is reliably false under the same conditions.

Perhaps the most annoying/perplexing part: when adding a debug print inside `func`, it returns the correct value. The same happens when I add `Sleep(500)`. This makes me suspect some kind of multithreading shenanigans, but as I said - only one place in the code where the `some_var` is assigned true, and it isn't reached in this run.

Is there something with the interaction of C# and C++ that could account for this?

Comment: it would be good if you put the C# code in there ;)

Comment: Incorrect function signature causing UB? Multithreading? Some other part of the program writing in memory it shopuldn't write? Hard to tell without more info..

Comment: I've added the C# calling. The rest of it... well, I don't expect SO to find multithreading bugs in my code, I was specifically asking about C# and C++ interactions to see if there's some common pitfall there that I'm not aware of.

Comment: What is SomeStruct, does it have the exact same layout in C# and C++?

Comment: I added the structs' definitions in either language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608876/c-sharp-dllimport-with-c-boolean-function-not-returning-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to your problem can be to precede your declaration withe the following marshaling.

```
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
```

This may happen because C defines bool as 4 bytes int and C++ defines it as 1 byte. C# team decided to use 4 byte bool as default during PInvoke because most of the system API function use 4 bytes values as bool. If you want to change this behavior you have to do it with marshaling specifying that you want to use 1 byte value. Also another solution can be to try changing the return type from bool to int, that should also fix the issue.

For more information, have a look at the answer mentioned here:
[C# DllImport with C++ boolean function not returning correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608876/c-sharp-dllimport-with-c-boolean-function-not-returning-correctly)