# C# PInvoke returning invalid/wrong bool value, only when native code compiled in debug mode (OSX only)

Tags: clang, pinvoke, debug-symbols, macos-high-sierra

So, I have a weird issue. I am doing a simple PInvoke call to get a boolean from managed code.

**C/C++**

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT bool net_variant_getBool(NetVariantContainer* container)
{
    bool result = container->variant->getBool();

    // This function will only return the right value if I use the following code in OSX in release mode (debug works with or without it).
    // qDebug("Return value is: %d", result);

    return result;
}
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("QmlNet.dylib")]
static extern bool net_variant_getBool(IntPtr variant);
```

The code above, as is, works perfectly on Linux/Windows in either debug or release mode, and OSX *in debug mode only*.

On OSX in release mode, the resulting value in C# is wrong. If I attempt to log what the returning bool is (to figure out the issue), it prints out the right value, **and then the right value is returned!** That's right, the `qDebug` macro above that is commented out will *fix* my issue if compiled in. Wth?

This problem only presents it's self in Release mode on OSX/clang.

Here is the compilation output on OSX for both debug and release builds. https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/3949b7e86d6a4bfb59788dd0b7c44536

I'm utterly lost. Anybody have any ideas? I don't want to ship debug libs!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# DllImport with C++ boolean function not returning correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608876/c-sharp-dllimport-with-c-boolean-function-not-returning-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `bool` is a non-blittable type and can't be used as a return value. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types).

I changed my code to return a `byte` instead.

Comment: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608876/c-sharp-dllimport-with-c-boolean-function-not-returning-correctly