# Access C++ DLL from C# program

Tags: c#, interop, dllimport

I'm very new to interop and I am having trouble defining the dll imports from a C++  DLL.  The documentation for the DLL is as follows:

```
bool __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) InitHW(char *name, char *model, int& type)
```

So the code I tried is as follows and it gives a system.AccessViolation exception:

```
[DllImport("extIO_IC7610.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public unsafe static extern bool InitHW(string name, string model, int type);

private unsafe void Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        bool result;

        string name = "Test";
        string model = "Model";
        int type = 3;

        result = InitHW(name, model, type);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

I just realized this is supposed to return data.
Could someone please show me the errors in my understanding here?
Thanks, Tom

Based on the comments I changed things to look like this:

```
[DllImport("extIO_IC7610.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] 
public unsafe static extern bool InitHW(string name, string model, ref int type);

unsafe private void Initialize())
{

    try
    {
        bool result;

        string name = ""; 
        string model = ""; 
        int type = 3;
        result = InitHW(name, model, ref type);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

This still does not work.  I now get an error that the stack is unbalanced due to the signatures not matching.  I think the strings are done correctly but the &int parameter may still be an issue.
Tom

Comment: I think you need `ref int type`... Not sure about the rest though I see no need for `unsafe`

Comment: Aside from the `ref int` already mentioned, note that the return type of your native C++ function is the C++ data type `bool`. Your DLLImport has to specifically account for that (the default marshalling for the C# data type `bool` is the native WinAPI type `BOOL`, which is different from the C++ data type `bool`). Why and how to do this exactly, see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool/; or see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608876/c-sharp-dllimport-with-c-boolean-function-not-returning-correctly

Comment: also make sure you specify the string encoding that your dll expects!

Comment: Still get errors

Comment: Getting closer.  I need to use CallingConvention.StdCall.  That seems to work and I have no errors, but all returned parameters are null.  So something is still wrong with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it.  There were a couple of hints here but nothing really correct.  After looking around for the last several hours this is the solution:

```
    [DllImport("extIO_IC7610.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] 
    public unsafe static extern bool InitHW(StringBuilder name,  StringBuilder model, int* type);

unsafe void Initialize()
{
           bool result;

            int type = 0;
            var name = new StringBuilder(250);
            var model = new StringBuilder(250);

            result = InitHW(name, model, &type);

            string _name = name.ToString();
            string _model = model.ToString();
```

}

Comment: No need for unsafe. Use out int or ref int.

Comment: You are right.  I do have other functions that require unsafe.  I just didn't put them in. Thanks